# Autoload plugins folder in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The methods in the last two rows in the block are removed in Rails 3.

```
%w{ models controllers }.each do |dir|
  path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'app', dir)
  $LOAD_PATH << path
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load path
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_once_paths.delete(path)
end
```

I wonder how you could autoload the files in the plugins models and controllers folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`load_paths` and `load_once_paths` were renamed in Rails 3 :

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_once_paths
```